# MySQL Join tables with virtual columns

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, multiple-columns

I want make virtual columns. In `list` id primary table, and I need join virtual columns with 'data'.

```
Table: columns
+------+---------+-------------+
| [ID] | ID_USER |   DATENAME  |
+------+---------+-------------+
|   1  |   NULL  | Description |
+------+---------+-------------+
|   2  |   NULL  |     Cost    |
+------+---------+-------------+
|   3  |    2    |    Width    |
+------+---------+-------------+

Table: list
+----+-----------+------------+--------+
|[ID]|    NAME   |    DATE    |  COLOR |
+----+-----------+------------+--------+
|  1 |  234/2016 | 2016-06-06 |   red  |
+----+-----------+------------+--------+
|  2 | 1000/2016 | 2016-06-07 |  blue  |
+----+-----------+------------+--------+
|  3 | 3456/2016 | 2016-06-08 | yellow |
+----+-----------+------------+--------+


Table: data
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| ID_REPAIR | ID_COLUMN | VALUE |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|     1     |     1     |  aaaa |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|     1     |     2     |  10$  |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|     2     |     1     |  bbbb |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|     2     |     2     |  20$  |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|     3     |     1     |  cccc |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|     3     |     2     |  30$  |
+-----------+-----------+-------+


Result:
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------------+------+
| [ID] |    NAME   |    DATE    |  COLOR | Description | Cost |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------------+------+
|   1  |  234/2016 | 2016-06-06 |   red  |     aaaa    |  10$ |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------------+------+
|   2  | 1000/2016 | 2016-06-07 |  blue  |     bbbb    |  20$ |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------------+------+
|   3  | 3456/2016 | 2016-06-08 | yellow |     cccc    |  30$ |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------------+------+
```

In this query I get names `columns`:

```
SELECT * FROM `columns` WHERE `id_user` IS NULL
```

And in PHP save IDs to variable, but on test I want generate table with only second column. In below code I want generate result with `Cost` column, but always is insert `Description` column:

SQL:

```
SELECT `list`.`id`, `name`, `date`, `color`, `data`.`value`
FROM `list` 
INNER JOIN `data` ON `list`.`id` = `data`.`id_repair` WHERE `repair_data`.`id_column` = 2
```

I haven't idea how do INNER JOIN only WHERE id_column is equal 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of columns to be returned by a SELECT cannot be dynamically determined at execution time. The number of columns, and the datatype and name (or alias) assigned to each column must be specified in the `SELECT` list of the query. So let's start with that.

To have a SQL statement return the resultset as shown, the query would need to be of the form:

```
 SELECT l.id
      , l.name
      , l.date
      , l.color
      , (expr1)     AS `Description`
      , (expr2)     AS `Cost`
   FROM list l
    ...
```

Returning *six* columns.

As far as the expressions `expr1` and `expr2` you would use to return the `Description` and `Cost` columns, there are a couple of approaches to unwinding the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model back into the normative relational model.

The easiest to understand, but not necessarily the best option, would be to use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list. As an example:

```
 SELECT l.id
      , l.name
      , l.date
      , l.color
      , ( SELECT d.value
            FROM `data` d
           WHERE d.id_repair = l.id
             AND d.id_column = 1
           ORDER BY d.value
           LIMIT 1
        )                      AS `Description`
      , ( SELECT c.value
            FROM `data` c
           WHERE c.id_repair = l.id
             AND c.id_column = 2
           ORDER BY c.value
           LIMIT 1
        )                      AS `Cost`
      , ( SELECT w.value
            FROM `data` w
           WHERE w.id_repair = l.id
             AND w.id_column = 3
           ORDER BY w.value
           LIMIT 1
        )                      AS `Width`
   FROM list l
  ORDER BY l.id
```

Note that a correlated subquery in the SELECT list can return no more than one row, and return a single expression. That is, it returns a *single* value.

---

As an alternative, we can make use of an outer join operation, and conditional aggregation. For example:

```
 SELECT l.id
      , l.name
      , l.date
      , l.color
      , MAX(IF(d.id_column=1,d.value,NULL)) AS `Description`
      , MAX(IF(d.id_column=2,d.value,NULL)) AS `Cost`
      , MAX(IF(d.id_column=3,d.value,NULL)) AS `Width`
   FROM list l
   LEFT
   JOIN data d
     ON d.id_repair = l.id 
  GROUP BY l.id, l.name, l.date, l.color
```

---

If we need to make the returned result *dynamic*, with a varying number of columns, and expressions used for the columns, based on information stored in tables in the database, then we could first fetch the information from the database, and then use that to help us construct the actual SQL statement we would need to execute to get the final result.

Or, as many application that make use of the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model do, we don't even try to force the EAV model back into a normative relational model. We just have the application run multiple queries that are needed to retrieve the information from the tables. Basically the reverse of how the application inserts rows into the tables.